# Should I use unwind segues when using multiple drill down windows to add something?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, segue

In "My First iOS App" you learn how to use an unwind segue to add "To Do List Items" to a To-Do List Table View Controller.

What if you are making an app with multiple new views and segues. For example, maybe you have an app that adds movies. You press an add button to add a new item. From there you go to a new scene where you add, lets say, cast members. You choose all your cast members, and from there when you are finished, you go to another scene to add crew members lets say. After that you go to a new scene to add a synopsis lets say. After that you want to return back to your original Table View Controller that lets you add movies. That's 3 scenes back.

Is it best to make everything an unwind segue like in the first iOS app, or is there a better way to do this? Each of these scenes is its own view controller which will likely have data to save along the way. The 3rd will save the synposis, the 2nd the crew members, and the first the cast.

Is this the 'standard' practiced way to do this, or how should I be doing it.

Thanks, I appreciate everyone's help in advance. I'm currently learning and am wondering about the best ways to do things.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably present that UINavigationController for adding movies modally and on third screen you would dismiss that view Controller. Another way to do it is to use one UINavigationController, starting from your root ViewController (where you choose what to do - for example add movies), and when you get to that third screen, you do `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` and get user back to root.

Not sure if this is helpful, but as much as I understood your question, this should be the answer.

Cheers